# In this program I have written my own memcopy function. I am printing destination string in the main as shown below

Tags: c, string

Below is the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mymemcpy(void *f_dst, void *f_src, int n) {
    int j = 0;
    char *src = (char *)f_src;
    char *dst = (char *)f_dst;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        dst[j] = src[j];
    }
    dst[j] = "\0";
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char src[100] = "HELLO WORD";
    char dst[100];

    mymemcpy(dst, src, 10);
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       printf("%c\t", dst[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%s", dst);
   
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as below

```
H       E       L       L       O               W       O       R       D
HELLO WORD$u
```

why I am getting the extra two characters in the second line of output even though in the function
I terminated the string with null character ?

Comment: `dst[j]="\0";` is wrong, it should be `dst[j]='\0';` with single quotes. Your compiler should be warning you about that

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks ,you are right it should be enclosed with single quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems:

- `dst[j] = "\0";` does not set a null terminator: you attempt to store a string pointer into a `char`. You should instead use a character constant as in `dst[j] = '\0';`
- `memcpy` does not write anything beyond the end of the destination array. `mymemcopy` probably should not either.  You should instead set the null terminator in `main` or pass a maximum count of character to `printf`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mymemcpy(void *f_dst, const void *f_src, size_t n) {
    size_t j = 0;
    unsigned char *src = (unsigned char *)f_src;
    unsigned char *dst = (unsigned char *)f_dst;
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        dst[j] = src[j];
    }
}

int main() {
    int i = 0;
    char src[100] = "HELLO WORD";
    char dst[100];

    mymemcpy(dst, src, 10);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       printf("%c\t", dst[i]);
    }
    printf("\n%.10s\n", dst);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alternative: `mymemcpy(dst, src, strlen(src) + 1);` to get the null terminator copied too.